# How I can get LatLng class from Mapbox library?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have updated a Mapbox library to the last version. Now I can't find a LatLng class.

With this package (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng) LatLng class isn't available at all. In the official documentation I cant find this class. Perhaps they replaced this class by another one.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I am using 10.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this [`migrate-to-v10`](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/migrate-to-v10/) documentation you should use `Point`:

> In v10, all the LatLng related methods and parameters are replaced with Point. Remember that the latitude and longitude parameters are reversed between LatLng and Point.

**pre-v10:**

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
 .withLatLng(new LatLng(6.687337, 0.381457))
```

**v10:**

```
val circleOptions: CircleOptions = CircleOptions()
 .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(0.381457, 6.687337))
```